# Why are my variables being reset to zero every time I reopen my Main activity

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am currently creating an app for a university project. Within the app I use two php scripts - one to set data from variables within the app to a MySQL data base, and the other to retrieve data from the database and set the variables within the app. The first script that sends the data to mySQL is working fine with no issues, however the script to retrieve the data from mySQL to set variables within the app is only working when ran through my webserver. When run within my app (on Activity Start and create) the variables are all set to zero. Any help would be amazing, Ive been stuck for weeks!

```php
<?php

require "conn.php";

$username = "test";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT gold, goldMulti, xp, xpMulti, xpMax, xpMaxMulti, dmg, dmgMulti, bossCount, bossHp, bossHpMulti, level, backgroundCount FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

$stmt ->execute();
$stmt ->bind_result($gold, $goldMulti, $xp, $xpMulti, $xpMax, $xpMaxMulti, $dmg, $dmgMulti, $bossCount, $bossHp, $bossHpMulti, $level, $backgroundCount);

$varaibles = array();

$stmt ->fetch();

$temp = array();

$temp['gold'] = $gold;
$temp['goldMulti'] = $goldMulti;
$temp['xp'] = $xp;
$temp['xpMulti'] = $xpMulti;
$temp['xpMax'] = $xpMax;
$temp['xpMaxMulti'] = $xpMaxMulti;
$temp['dmg'] = $dmg;
$temp['dmgMulti'] = $dmgMulti;
$temp['bossCount'] = $bossCount;
$temp['bossHp'] = $bossHp;
$temp['bossHpMulti'] = $bossHpMulti;
$temp['level'] = $level;
$temp['backgroundCount'] = $backgroundCount;


array_push($variables,$temp);

echo json_encode($temp);

?>
```

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // int variables for logic and functions ------------------------------------------------------
    public int gold;
    public int goldAwarded;
    public int goldMultiplier;
    public int xp;
    public int xpAwarded;
    public int xpMultiplier;
    public int dmg;
    public int dmgMultiplier;
    public int bossCount;
    public int bossHP;
    public int bossHPMultiplier;
    public int bossHPBase;
    public int level;
    public int xpMax;
    public int bossCountFunc;
    public int backgroundCount;
    public int xpMaxMulti;
    public int baseDmg;


// Widget variables -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private TextView bossNumberText;
    private TextView levelText;
    private TextView goldText;
    private TextView bossHealthText;
    private ImageButton tapButton;
    private ImageView bossImage;
    private ImageView playerImage;
    private ImageView bossImage2;
    private ImageView bossImage3;
    private ImageButton shopButton;
    public String LoggedInUser = LogIn.getUser();

// Audio players --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MediaPlayer mps;
    MediaPlayer mpb;
    MediaPlayer mpc;
    MediaPlayer mpl;
    MediaPlayer mpp;



// Websever php file URL to retrieve Data from user ----------------------------------------------

    private static final String URL = "http://jg1104.brighton.domains/AppPhp/variablesretrieval.php";

    private void getData(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try{

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            gold = object.getInt("gold");
                            goldMultiplier = object.getInt("goldMulti");
                            xp = object.getInt("xp");
                            xpMultiplier = object.getInt("xpMulti");
                            xpMax = object.getInt("xpMax");
                            xpMaxMulti = object.getInt("xpMaxMulti");
                            dmg = object.getInt("dmg");
                            dmgMultiplier = object.getInt("dmgMulti");
                            bossCount = object.getInt("bossCount");
                            bossHP = object.getInt("bossHp");
                            bossHPMultiplier = object.getInt("bossHpMulti");
                            level = object.getInt("level");
                            backgroundCount = object.getInt("backgroundCount");

                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("LoggedInUser", LoggedInUser);


                return param;
            }
        }
        );

        Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this).add(stringRequest);
    }




    // On create -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bossNumberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bossNumberText);
        levelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelText);
        goldText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.goldText);
        bossHealthText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bossHealthText);
        tapButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.TapButton);
        bossImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bossImage);
        playerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerImage);
        bossImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bossImage2);
        bossImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bossImage3);
        shopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.shopButton);

        mpb = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
        mpc = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coin);
        mpl = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.levelup);
        mpp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pain);
        mps = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shootingsound);

        // retrieving data from database and setting TextViews -----------------------------------
        getData();

        // Set looping and start of background music ---------------------------------------------
        mpb.setLooping(true);
        mpb.start();
        // Initialising variable values on create ------------------------------------------------
        goldAwarded = 100;
        xpAwarded = 100;
        baseDmg = 1;
        bossHPBase = 10;
        bossCountFunc = 1;


        shopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchShop();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
            protected void onStart() {
        // onclickListener for main button --------------------------------------------------------
        super.onStart();
        getData();
        levelText.setText("Level: " + Integer.toString(level));
        goldText.setText("Gold: " + Integer.toString(gold));
        bossHealthText.setText("HP: " + Integer.toString(bossHP));
        bossNumberText.setText("Boss: " + bossCount);

        tapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // shooting sound
                mps.start();
                // run method that looks to see if background needs to be changed
                newBackground();
                // handlers for enemy animations
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        bossImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onezshot));
                        AnimationDrawable oneshotz = (AnimationDrawable) bossImage.getDrawable();
                        oneshotz.start();


                    }
                }, 0);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        bossImage2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twozshot));
                        AnimationDrawable twozshot = (AnimationDrawable) bossImage2.getDrawable();
                        twozshot.start();


                    }
                }, 0);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        bossImage3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.threezshot));
                        AnimationDrawable threezshot = (AnimationDrawable) bossImage3.getDrawable();
                        threezshot.start();


                    }
                }, 0);
                // handler for shooting animation
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        playerImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shooting));
                        AnimationDrawable shooting = (AnimationDrawable) playerImage.getDrawable();
                        shooting.start();

                    }
                }, 0);

                bossHP -= dmg;
                bossHealthText.setText("HP: " + Integer.toString(bossHP));
                // if boss dies
                if (bossHP <= 1) {
                    mpp.start();
                    bossCount++;
                    bossCountFunc++;
                    backgroundCount++;
                    if (backgroundCount > 9) {
                        backgroundCount = 1;
                    }
                    if (bossCountFunc > 3) {
                        bossCountFunc = 1;
                    }
                    bossNumberText.setText("Boss: " + bossCount);
                    goldMultiplier++;
                    xpMultiplier++;
                    mpc.start();
                    gold += (goldAwarded * goldMultiplier);
                    goldText.setText("Gold: " + Integer.toString(gold));
                    xp += (xpAwarded * xpMultiplier);
                    bossHPMultiplier++;
                    // look for level up
                    if (xp >= xpMax) {
                        mpl.start();
                        level++;
                        dmgMultiplier++;
                        bossHPMultiplier *= 2;
                        dmg = (baseDmg * dmgMultiplier);
                        levelText.setText("lvl: " + Integer.toString(level));
                        xp = 0;
                        xpMax = xpMax * xpMaxMulti;
                    }
                    newBoss();
                }
            }
        });


    }
    // Method to show or hide boss frames
    public void newBoss(){
        bossHP = bossHPBase * bossHPMultiplier;

        if(bossCountFunc==1){
            bossImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bossImage2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bossImage3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }


        if(bossCountFunc==2){
            bossImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bossImage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
        if(bossCountFunc==3){
            bossImage2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bossImage3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
    // method to check and change background
    public void newBackground(){
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

        if(backgroundCount<=3){
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main);
        }
        if(backgroundCount>3 && backgroundCount<=6){
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.maintwo);
        }
        if(backgroundCount>6 && backgroundCount<=9){
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainthree);

        }

    }


    public void launchShop(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Shop.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void setData(final String LoggedInUser, final int gold,final int goldMultiplier,final int xp,final int xpMultiplier
            ,final int xpMax,final int xpMaxMulti,final int dmg
            ,final int dmgMultiplier,final int bossCount,final int bossHP
            ,final int bossHPMultiplier,final int level,final int backgroundCount){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Setting Data");
        progressDialog.show();
        String uRl = "http://jg1104.brighton.domains/AppPhp/setdata.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.equals("Data set")){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("LoggedInUser", LoggedInUser);
                param.put("gold", Integer.toString(gold));
                param.put("goldMulti", Integer.toString(goldMultiplier));
                param.put("xp", Integer.toString(xp));
                param.put("xpMulti", Integer.toString(xpMultiplier));
                param.put("xpMax", Integer.toString(xpMax));
                param.put("xpMaxMulti", Integer.toString(xpMaxMulti));
                param.put("dmg", Integer.toString(dmg));
                param.put("dmgMulti", Integer.toString(dmgMultiplier));
                param.put("bossCount", Integer.toString(bossCount));
                param.put("bossHp", Integer.toString(bossHP));
                param.put("bossHpMulti", Integer.toString(bossHPMultiplier));
                param.put("level", Integer.toString(level));
                param.put("backgroundCount", Integer.toString(backgroundCount));
                return param;
            }
        };

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        setData(LoggedInUser,gold,goldMultiplier,xp,xpMultiplier,xpMax,xpMaxMulti,dmg,dmgMultiplier,bossCount,bossHP,bossHPMultiplier,level,backgroundCount);
    }

}
```

Since the script is working when used in my webserver, I am sure it is something to do with my java coding.

Comment: Prepared statement is being misused here. `FROM users WHERE username = ?` then bind `$username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is your problem:

```
try{
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        gold = object.getInt("gold");
        goldMultiplier = object.getInt("goldMulti");
        xp = object.getInt("xp");
        xpMultiplier = object.getInt("xpMulti");
        xpMax = object.getInt("xpMax");
        xpMaxMulti = object.getInt("xpMaxMulti");
        dmg = object.getInt("dmg");
        dmgMultiplier = object.getInt("dmgMulti");
        bossCount = object.getInt("bossCount");
        bossHP = object.getInt("bossHp");
        bossHPMultiplier = object.getInt("bossHpMulti");
        level = object.getInt("level");
        backgroundCount = object.getInt("backgroundCount");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

You should not leave the catch block empty. It's likely throwing and swallowing an error.

Do this:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyApp", "Error parsing!", e);
    }
```

(Some reading on Logcat https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)
or get rid of the try catch all together and let your app crash (fail fast)!!

---

Your actual error (or first error I can see anyway) is that you are attempting to parse a JSONarray when your server side response is a JSONObject. This line of code:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
```

And this response:

```
{
   "gold":600, "goldMulti":3,
   "xp":0, "xpMulti":3, "xpMax":0, "xpMaxMulti":0,
   "dmg":3,"dmgMulti":3,
   "bossCount":3,
   "bossHp":80, 
   "bossHpMulti":14,
   "level":3,
   "backgroundCount":3
}
```

(from here) http://jg1104.brighton.domains/AppPhp/variablesretrieval.php

You should parse it as a `JsonObject` or wrap your server side returned response in an Array `[]`.